# Identification of legitimate distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

I'm completely new in this, so help me please.

$F(t)$ is the distribution function. $G(t)$ is the limit of $F^n(t)$ as $n\to\infty$. Is it true that $G(t)$ is the distribution function?

$F(t)$ is the distribution function. $G(t)$ is the limit of $F(n-t)$ as $n\to\infty$. Is it true that $G(t)$ is the distribution function?

Another stupid question:
$f(t)$ is the probability density function. $g(t)=2f(-2t)$ is also the probability density function because of $g(t)\geq0$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2f(-2t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-2t)d2t=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=1$$
my question is why $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-2t)d2t$ equals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ and not minus $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$?

Comment: For your second question, remember that you have to apply the change of variables to the limits of the integral, also, which makes the bottom limit $\infty$ and the top limit $-\infty$' reversing the signs again.

Comment: Are you asking about cumulative distribution functions?  The last question is a simple matter of u-substitution and changing the limits of integration to account for the sign change cancelling out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $F_{n}$ defined by $x\mapsto1$ if $x\geq\frac{1}{n}$ and $x\mapsto0$
otherwise is a distribution function. Limit $G$ defined by $x\mapsto1$
if $x>0$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise is not. This because it is not continuous 'from the right'.

**Edit of OP made 1) irrelevant.**

2) If $G$ is the limit of $G_n(t):= F(n-t)$ where $F$ is a distribution function then $G(t)=1$ for each $t$ hence is not a distribution function. Notice here that $G_n$ is not a distribution function either.

3) Informally: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(-x\right)dx=-\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)dx$.
The (unusual) sign $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}$ must be changed into
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ and that gives you a second minus neutralizing
the first.

**addendum after edit OP.**

If $G$ is the limit of $F^n$ then $G(t)=1$ if $F(t)=1$ and $G(t)=0$ otherwise. Here $G$  is a distribution function if and only if $F(t)=1$ for some $t$.